# Facebook graph API - Show profile pic - Not working on Samsung Galaxy S3

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, galaxy

I am trying to show a profile pic trought the graph api. Here is my link :

http://graph.facebook.com/wmaker/picture?type=large&width=180&height=180

On all devices, be it iPhone, Windows Phone, desktops, or even Androids (tested on 2.3 and 4.4), this link redirects to a PNG image

On my Galaxy S3 (chrome) though, it cannot load the link, and never gets redirected

I have no clue about why it should behave like this.

Any idea ?

Comment: What is the HTTP response when you do that request on Galaxy S3?

Comment: doesn't respond, keep loading indefinitely (or timeout)

Comment: And you know that it is the HTTP request that loads forever and not something else?